# ¿Como puedo cambiar el nombre de una imagen al momento de guardar la imagen en una carpeta y en la base de datos?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Lo que quiero saber es como cambiar el nombre a una imagen que pediré en un formulario html para guardar su nombre y extensión en la base de datos y la imagen en una carpeta correspondiente.

Lo que no quiero es que si un usuario sube una imagen con el mismo nombre de otra ya existente se cree un conflicto al momento de mostrarla o hacer uso de ella.

Comment: No dices dónde se encuentran tus imágenes, ¿en tu pc, en un servidor remoto, disponibles a través de internet? Tampoco se entiende bien lo de _cambiar el nombre a una imagen_ Para que la pregunta quede más clara creo que es mejor detallar lo que quieres hacer, paso por paso.

Comment: por eso dije si un usuario sube una imagen obviamente la imagen no va estar en mi pc sino en la pc de el cliente y por lo del nombre creo que es mas que entendible que lo que quiero es cambiarle el nombre a la imagen al momento de hacer el guardado en el servidor para que no cree conflictos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta que te dio @A.Cedano está excelente para partir. Yo te aconsejaría que *siempre* asumas que el archivo ya existe, y por tanto tienes que renombrarlo.

El problema es que si el archivo `mi_imagen.png` ya existe, no puedes simplemente ponerle `mi_imagen2.png` porque primero hay que comprobar si `mi_imagen2.png` existe.

La solución en estos casos es asignar un nombre que no se pueda repetir. Por ejemplo usando el timestamp.

```
    $name = basename($_FILES["imagenes"]["name"][$key]);
    list($base,$extension) = explode('.',$name);
    $newname = implode('.', [$base, time(), $extension];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$newname");
```

Y en ese caso tu archivos se llamarían de la forma `mi_imagen.1489403902.png`.

Según la solución propuesta, lo único que te faltaría sería contemplar el caso que el nombre del archivo contenga un punto entre medio, pero eso queda como tarea para ti.

Mejor que el timestamp sería usar un generador de UUIDs, pero la idea no es complicarte tanto las cosas.

Comment: Exelente me diste una buena opción

Answer (score 0):

Si, lo haces en el servidor. aqui tienes la [documentacion](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

puedes generar un nombre nuevo, se utiliza, depende el caso, las fechas los id de usuarios y cosas asi.

```
<?php
// In PHP versions earlier than 4.1.0, $HTTP_POST_FILES should be used instead
// of $_FILES.

$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

Seria algo asi:

```
$_FILES['userfile']['name'] //es el nombre original.

$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] //es el nombre que tiene en el servidor

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfolder.'el_nombre_que_yo_quiera.jpg')//
```

Cuando digo nombre me refiero al "path" del archivo en el servidor

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo así más o menos.

**HTML**

```html
 

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="subir-imagen" action="enviar_imagen.php">
<input type="file" name="imagenes" id="imagenes" multiple accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg" />
<button type="submit" id="btn">Subir Imagenes</button>
</form>
<div id="respuesta"></div>
<ul id="imagenes-lista">
</ul>
```

**PHP**

Este es el PHP al que Ajax enviará la imagen y él se encargará de guardarla en el servidor.
[Ver Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.files.php)

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["imagenes"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["imagenes"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        // basename() puede evitar ataques de denegación de sistema de ficheros;
        // podría ser apropiada más validación/saneamiento del nombre del fichero
        $name = basename($_FILES["imagenes"]["name"][$key]);
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
?>

echo "<h2>Imágenes subidas con éxito</h2>";
```

**Javascript/Ajax**

```
(function () {
var input = document.getElementById("imagenes"), 
    formdata = false;

function showUploadedItem (source) {
    var list = document.getElementById("imagenes-lista"),
        li   = document.createElement("li"),
        img  = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = source;
    li.appendChild(img);
    list.appendChild(li);
}   

if (window.FormData) {
    formdata = new FormData();
    document.getElementById("btn").style.display = "none";
}

input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
    document.getElementById("respuesta").innerHTML = "Subiendo . . ."
    var i = 0, len = this.files.length, img, reader, file;

    for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
        file = this.files[i];

        if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
            if ( window.FileReader ) {
                reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function (e) { 
                    showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
            if (formdata) {
                formdata.append("imagenes[]", file);
            }
        }   
    }

    if (formdata) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "enviar_imagen.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (res) {
                document.getElementById("respuesta").innerHTML = res;
            }
        });
    }
}, false);
}());
```

Comment: Ahora bien al momento de guardar el archivo en la carpeta destino en que momento le cambias el nombre para evitar que dos archivos se llamen igual?

Comment: @ivanrangel te he puesto un modelo del código. Analízalo y adáptalo a lo que necesitas. Por ejemplo puedes tener un array con los nombres de imágenes y buscar en él si el nombre de la nueva imagen está.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte